# Shiny - barplot with aggregates based on checkbox

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to display a simple barplot that aggregates a sales quantity based on which individuals are selected by a checkbox.

I am hoping to see the unique dates on the x-axis and the quantities on the y-axis. I am hoping that the "default" value shows the sum for each of the three individuals. Finally, if anyone is feeling extra generous I'd love it if they could be stacked on top of each other on the bar graph.

I have done a lot of searching and can't find anything that explains how to do this, though undoubtedly it is out there.

I am specifically confused over what to put into the barplot() function.

Thank you in advance for your help.

ui.R

```
library(shiny)

fluidPage(    

          titlePanel("Sales by individual"),

          sidebarLayout(      
              sidebarPanel(
                  checkboxGroupInput("person", "Person:", 
                  choices=unique(df$person)),
                  hr(),
                  helpText("n/a")),

          mainPanel(plotOutput("salesPlot"))))
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)

date = c('2018-05-15', '2018-05-15', '2018-05-16', '2018-05-16', '2018-05-16', '2018-05-14', '2018-05-14', '2018-05-14')
person = c("Dwight", "Jim", "Dwight", "Pam", "Jim", "Pam", "Jim", "Dwight")
quantity = c(10, 15, 25, 35, 14, 12, 1, 10)

df = data.frame(date, person, quantity)
df$person <- as.character(df$person)
df$date <- as.character(df$date)
df$date <- as.Date(df$date, format="%Y-%m-%d")

function(input, output) {


  output$salesPlot <- renderPlot({


    barplot(
            #Do not understand what to put here



            ylab="Number of Sales",
            xlab="Date")
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a few options but here is one:

```
ui = fluidPage(    

  titlePanel("Sales by individual"),

  sidebarLayout(      
    sidebarPanel(
      checkboxGroupInput("person", "Person:", 
                         choices=unique(df$person), selected = unique(df$person)),
      hr(),
      helpText("n/a")),

    mainPanel(plotOutput("salesPlot"))))


server = function(input, output) {


  dataplot <- eventReactive(input$person, {
    df <- df %>% filter(as.factor(person) %in% c(input$person))
  })



  output$salesPlot <- renderPlot({


      ggplot(data = dataplot(), aes(x = date, y = quantity, fill = person)) + geom_col(position = position_stack()) + theme_bw() + xlab("Date") + ylab("Number of Sales")


  })
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: have you tried `+
annotate("text", x = -71.82718, y = -34.56935, label = "TESTING")`?